# Max Payne - Max Payne 2 Resolution / Perspective issue on a wide screen monitor

Tags: pc, max-payne-2, max-payne

So just bought Max Payne and Max Payne 2 from the Steam Sale. Is there a way to change the perspective of the game, so  that it doesn't look weird on a Wide Screen monitor.

I am able to set it 1680x1050, but then everything looks Wide(fat). Is there a way to fix that, or should I stick to a 4:3 resolution and turn of scaling for my monitor/graphics card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a shred of evidence on [Widescreen Gaming Forum](http://www.widescreengamingforum.com/wiki/Max_Payne_series) (the definitive source for widescreen game support and fixes) that you can get an acceptable display in widescreen resolutions.  The game simply stretches the image to fill your monitor, just as you described.

I would recommend sticking with your second idea of running the game pillarboxed at a 4:3 display ratio.

Comment: Having just replayed MP 1 and 2, I concur with this answer.  You may also need this: http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=848215

Answer (score 1):

Install [ThirteenAG's widescreen fix](https://thirteenag.github.io/wfp#mp1) to fix stretching in widescreen resolutions.

Max Payne:

[image: stretched]

[image: correct]

Max Payne 2:

[image: stretched]

[image: correct]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but the above post is no longer correct, I have been playing Max Payne 1 and 2 recently and these tricks are what worked for me.

**Max Payne**, is somewhat annoying as every-time the level loads you have to do this.

Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> then type in (case sensitive)

```
MaxPayne_GameMode->GM_ChangeFOV(1.2,0);
```

Once you type it in correctly you can always just press the up arrow and bring back the command.

**Max Payne 2**, is a lot easier and you only have to make one config file change ever.  Inside the Max Payne 2 directory there will be a file called `MP2_init.ras` , open it with your text editor of choice and edit the line `DefaultFOV = 70` to `DefaultFOV = 85`.

The above will work permanently and you only have to do it once.

Both of these above methods I learned from [WSGF](http://www.wsgf.org)

[WSGF Max Payne Guide](http://www.wsgf.org/dr/max-payne)

[WSGF Max Payne II Guide](http://www.wsgf.org/node/238)

Comment: Changing FOV doesn't fix aspect ratio stretching.